# Adding a colour class to an element in scss based on existence of element

Tags: css, laravel, sass

I have an article block that looks like this:

[image]

The SCSS for this box is here:

```
/* Styling for all articles on index page */

#news-grid {
    .article {
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: left;
        border: none;
        .article-featured-image-box {
            position: relative;
            .featured-image {
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        }
        .article-meta-information {
            color: #cacacd;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: $balto-font;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .article-content {
            padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        .article-title {
            font-family: $circular-font;
            color: $newable-navy;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            a {
                color: $newable-navy;
            }
        }
        .article-body {
            line-height: 24px;
            font-family: $balto-font;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 300;
            p {
                line-height: 24px;
                font-family: $balto-font;
                color: $newable-dark-grey;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: 300;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                a {
                    color: $newable-blue;
                }
            }
            a {
                color: $newable-blue;
            }
            .article-excerpt p {
                line-height: 24px;
                font-family: CircularStd;
                color: $newable-navy;
                font-size: 21px;
                font-weight: 500;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        }
        .article-footer {
            padding-top: 15px;
            border-top: 1px solid $newable-grey;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }
        .interactions-panel {
            width: auto;
            float: right;
        }
        .sticker {
            background-color: #fff;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: #282C35;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 45px;
            width: 45px;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking to do is add a class that dictates colour, for instance, if an image is not provided I want the news article to have a dark theme.

This class `.dark` will change the background colour, text colour and title colour.

The articles are generated using a foreach loop

```
@foreach($articles as $article)

    <div class="grid-item element-item {{ str_slug($article->category) }}">

        <div class="article">

            <div class="article-featured-image-box">

                @if($article->featuredVideo != NULL) 

                    {!! $article->featuredVideo !!} 

                @else

                    <img class="featured-image" style="width: 100%; height:auto;" src="{{ $article->featuredImage }}" alt="{{ $article->title }}"> 

                @endif 

                @if($article->featuredArticle)

                    <div class="sticker yellow">
                        <span class="icon icon-news"></span>
                    </div>

                @endif

            </div>

            <div class="article">
                <div class="article-content">

                    <div class="article-meta-information">
                        {{ $article->created_at->format('d F Y') }} | {{ $article->author }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="article-title">
                        <a href="{{ action('ArticleController@show', [$article->id, str_slug($article->title)]) }}">{{ $article->title }}</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="article-body">
                        <p>{{ $article->excerpt }}</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

At the top of the foreach I can check if there is a featured image and redefine `<div class="article">` to `<div class="article dark">`

Is there a way in SaSS that I can say if the class is `.article .dark` change the colours of the inner elements, or would I have to have a separate bunch of styling?

Also, would you just hide the featured image box or redefine the whole block?

I'd essentially like to be able to have many themes for the article block in which I can append a class to control the colouring.

This is probably really simple but I've hit a wall

Comment: If you have a class .dark, you should be able to put styling in the scss for .dark and it will override the styling for .article

Comment: But within `.dark` would I have to override the nested elements?

Comment: But if you wanted to make it more specific, you can have a `.article` section as well as a `.article.dark` section in your scss. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/).

Comment: So would I have to have `.dark{.article-title{color:white}}`

Comment: I see what you're asking. I believe you can just make a `.dark` class and change only what you want to change from the `.article` class

Comment: Okay, is there a way to say if the parent has `.dark` give dark styling to child elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a aggregate class to the `.article` class using `&`:

```
#news-grid {
    .article {

        // Your current styles and nested classes...

        // When .article.dark
        &.dark {

            // Your custom overrides
            .article-title {
                color: white;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I built a working compilation example [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9e3aac10229376dfd9dc6bc23205d050). Note that i added some variables at the top just to make the code work.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good use for [Sass maps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps).

You could create your two themes (light and dark) as maps, then use them in a mixin, switching themes by passing an argument to the mixin. For example:

```
// All styles for .article go here
@mixin article($theme) {
  background-color: map-get($theme, main-bg);

  .article-title {
    color: map-get($theme, title-col);
  }
}

// Colours stored as Sass maps
$theme--light: (
  main-bg: gainsboro,
  title-col: dimgrey
);

$theme--dark: (
  main-bg: darkslategrey,
  title-col: whitesmoke
);

// Finally, here we call the mixin, passing name of the correct map
.article {
  @include article($theme--light);
}

.article.dark {
  @include article($theme--dark);
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.article {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.article .article-title {
  color: dimgrey;
}

.article.dark {
  background-color: darkslategrey;
}

.article.dark .article-title {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```